# Refreshing a LRU cache

Tags: java, caching, linkedhashmap, lru

I am implementing a cache using a map extended from LinkedHashMap (so I can implement removeEldestEntry). The old implementation used a regular hash map, refreshed at a set interval. I was wondering how I can keep the data in the cache current. I doubt I can just refresh at a specific time without messing up the point of LRU. Would it be particularly costly to query the DB for a time stamp on the entry?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29 EldestEntry is _number based_, not time-based. In LRU, you want a minimum survival time -- a constrain in time, EledestEntry caps the length -- a constraint in size. I am wondering, how are you planning to implement LRU using EldestEntry?

Comment: @Nishant, I was under the impression that LRU simply governed what got removed, not when. When I hit my size constraint, I want to remove the object that was least recently used.

Comment: LRU -- least-recently-used, as I know it, should remove the oldest entry. In other word, you want to remove object that is requested the least frequently. Now, your hashmap of size, say, 100 and the 100th element is the most-frequently-used, would you like to remove it? There are two escapes (1) use priority queue with priority decided on the time-stamp when the object was added (2) Use LHM but every time, when get() is called, remove the entry and re-insert in the map to mimick LRU.

Comment: @Nishant, The third parameter of one of LinkedHashMap's constructors is boolean accessOrder. Setting that to true orders the data by when it is accessed.

Comment: ah, alright. Should have looked in more deeply -- totally messed up KISS. Anyways, thanks for pointing. it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the LinkedHashMap, ordered by access time and checking against the db for timestamps. This worked like a charm and greatly reduced the memory load of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [OS Cache](http://www.opensymphony.com/oscache/) - no point in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Or any other cache for that matter. Most have a time to live setting

Comment: The reason being is that this is a very old project and none of the original developers remain. I would like to avoid adding any new dependencies and just rewire a single file.

Comment: @Bobnix. Perhaps, but I'm of the opinion you should not cut corners. :)

Comment: I gotta agree here. It's not just cutting corners. There's a high probability you will get this wrong. It's not worth the possible bugs you induce, trying to re-implement this. The same reason you don't go reimplement things like linked lists, hash maps, sorting functions, etc.